# Intepretting Linear Mixed Effects Model Output

Tags: mixed-model, least-squares

I'm trying to reconcile the output of this MixedLM Model Output with my knowledge of OLS model outputs, e.g., MixedLM has Z-Stats vs. T-Stats for OLS. Model code for reference, but this is not my question:

```
model = smf.mixedlm('yVar ~ gas_prices + xVar2 ', dfModel, 
                 groups = dfModel['region'])
mdf = model.fit()
print(mdf.summary())
```

For the below, how do I interpret the `Intercept RE` variable:

```
                Mixed Linear Model Regression Results
======================================================================
Model:                MixedLM   Dependent Variable:   yVar 
No. Observations:     420       Method:               REML            
No. Groups:           4         Scale:                45635645671.2271
Min. group size:      105       Likelihood:           -5720.8133      
Max. group size:      105       Converged:            Yes             
Mean group size:      105.0                                           
----------------------------------------------------------------------
              Coef.     Std.Err.    z    P>|z|    [0.025      0.975]  
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept  3241461.947 112718.823 28.757 0.000 3020537.112 3462386.781
gas_prices -118128.471  46931.809 -2.517 0.012 -210113.126  -26143.816
xVar2          275.017    165.072  1.666 0.096     -48.518     598.553
groups RE        0.002                                                
======================================================================
```

Three main questions:
+ `groups RE` has no `Std.Err` or `z` so I can't determine statistical significance. How do I know that this has an significant impact?
+ As I add variables to the model, I'll be rebuilding it to show each variable's explanatory power and contribution: how do I factor in `groups RE`? Is it a `constant` that I should multiply by it's respective coefficient?
+ I was under the impression that I would see different impacts of each `x variable` by region, but it appears that region is on it's own. What modeling framework will show the varying impact of the `x variables` broken-out by the categorical variable (in this case, `region`)?